# I want to be able to sync timelog between GanttPRO and ur internal log system

Tags: api

Is there any official or unofficial GanttPRO API available?
If GanttPRO can post a webhook each time when new time log created - it's enough for us
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dmitry, we plan to release a public API  at the mid of September 2020.
I'll provide a link for the documentation here

Thanks

Comment: thanks, Danik
waiting for it